# How to update subview in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I have a Parent view and I want to update the child view from Parent's ViewModel. Within the child view there is loop which is iterating over an array of Integer I want to pass this array after an API call but when I am passing the data after the API response the loop of the child view is not getting iterated.

Parent View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SeatSelectionView: View {
    
    @StateObject var seatLayoutViewModel = SeatLayoutViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                VStack(spacing: -5) {
                    HStack {
                        GateSectionView(data: seatLayoutViewModel.totalSeats).frame(width: 780)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom)
                
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
            .onAppear {
                seatLayoutViewModel.getSeatMasterData()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Child View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GateSectionView: View {
    
    @State private var data:[Int] = [Int]()
    
    
    private let adaptiveColumns = [
        
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 30))
    ]
    
    init(data: [Int]) {
        self.data = data
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns) {
                ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                    Text("Helo")
                }
            }.padding(10)
            Spacer()
            
        }.cornerRadius(12).frame(width: 780)
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
import Foundation
class SeatLayoutViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var totalSeats:[Int] = [Int]()
    
    func getSeatMasterData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
            self.totalSeats = Array(1...20)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `@Binding` without the `private` and `$` in the call.
So when the data changes it will trigger a child view refresh.

```
struct GateSectionView: View {
    @Binding var data:[Int] // <-- here @Binding

    private let adaptiveColumns = [ GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80)) ]  // <--
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns) {
                ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                    Text("Helo \(index)") // <--
                }
            }.padding(10)
            Spacer()
        }.cornerRadius(12).frame(width: 780)
    }
}

struct SeatSelectionView: View {
    @StateObject var seatLayoutViewModel = SeatLayoutViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                VStack(spacing: -5) {
                    HStack {
                        GateSectionView(data: $seatLayoutViewModel.totalSeats) // <-- here $
                            .frame(width: 780)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.bottom)
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear {
                seatLayoutViewModel.getSeatMasterData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `@State var data: [Int]` in `GateSectionView`
and

```
  GateSectionView(data: seatLayoutViewModel.totalSeats)
     .id(UUID())  // <--
```

to refresh the view.